# Point closest to curve in $R^m$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been working on a problem from a foundation exam which seems totally straightforward but for some reason I've become stuck:

Let $f: \mathbb{ R } \rightarrow \mathbb{ R } ^n$ be a differentiable mapping with $f^\prime (t) \ne 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{ R } $, and let $p \in \mathbb{ R } ^n$ be a point NOT in $f(\mathbb{ R }) $.

1. Show that there is a point $q = f(t)$ on the curve $f(\mathbb{ R }) $ which is closest to $p$.
2. Show that the vector $r := (p - q)$ is orthogonal to the curve at $q$.

Hint: Consider the function $t \mapsto |p - f(t)|$ and its derivative.

I can solve the second part of the problem assuming that I've found the point $q$ requested in the first part: consider the square difference function $\varphi(t) = |p - f(t)|^2 = (p - f(t)) \cdot (p - f(t))$, derive and at $q = f(t_0)$ we will have  $\varphi ^\prime(t_0) = 0$.  How do we prove the existence of the point $q$?  The square distance function $\varphi(t)$ is a function from $\mathbb{ R } \rightarrow \mathbb{ R }  $, so maybe something like Rolle's Theorem?  Not too sure about this.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement is actually wrong! Consider for example the function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2,\; t\mapsto (0,e^t)$ with the point $p=(0,0)$.

The problem here is that the domain of $f$ is not compact. If you consider a function on a closed interval $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ the statement becomes true.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. The function $\varphi: t\mapsto |p-f(t)|^2$ is continuous and positive, and therefore assumes a minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Take some $s$ on the curve. Take circle $C$ with center in $p$ of radius $|p-s|$. $\overline C \cap f(\mathbb{R}) - $ closed and bounded set (i.e. compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$). $t \to |p-f(t)|$ is continuous function. What do you know about continuous functions on compacts?